# Can a foreign key value be null when storing a record then update it when the value is known?

Tags: mysql

[image: ERP diagram]

This is a database for a web based library management system
We have for roles for the users: admin,librarian, borrower.

A borrower who has an online account can reserve books online, then when he goes to the library to pick it up if the librarian confirms the reservation as "picked up", the data in the reservation table will be stored in the "borrow" table automatically (by the backend)

So a book reservation is basically a borrow in advance .

In the borrow table we need to know the column (`supervised_by(FK)`) which is the librarian who did supervise that borrow and that will be already known if the borrower borrowed a book offline in the library.

But if the borrower reserved a book online, we still don't know who is the librarian who will supervise this reservation  later so it cannot be filled at that time, but at the same time this field is needed so later when the data of the reservation is copied to the borrow table . How can I handle this?

Someone suggested to me to remove the `supervisedby` column and use log files, but then we will not store the librarian who managed a borrow/reservation in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** yes.

**Long answer:** as long as you allow `NULL`s in your foreign key column, you can fill them with `NULL`s and update them later.

**Fun answer:** just try it.

The foreign key constraint only makes sure you do not put a non-existing key in there.

Comment: Yes, it's important to point out that constraints fail when they evaluate to false only. If they evaluate to true or unknown, they produce no effect.